# map find() function if the wanted key is in the last position

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am a C++ beginner. I know that `find()` is used to search for a certain key. This function returns an iterator to the element if the element is found, else it returns an iterator pointing to the last position of the. map i.e `map.end()`.
I read from websites that

```
if(it == mp.end())
    cout << "Key-value pair not present in map" ;
else
    cout << "Key-value pair present : "
```

What if the found key is in the end postition? How can it still work? Key is sorted in a certain order and I think the iterator traverses the sorted key to find the one we want. (is it correct?)

Comment: _"else it returns the pointer pointing to the last position "_ That is not true. It returns the _end_ iterator, which is distinct from the iterator to the last element. The end iterator is a special sentinel value which cannot be referenced.

Comment: Worth reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end

Answer (score 1):

The result of all `.end()` in the stl is beyond the valid values.  So end() will never be valid.

```
int arr[10];
// arr has valid indices 0,1,2,3,...,7,8,9
// arr[10] is not valid.
for( auto i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
}

std::vector vec;
vec.resize( 10 );
// vec.end() is equivalent to arr[10] - not part of the vector
for( auto it = vec.begin(); vec != vec.end(); vec++ ) {
}
```

So lets re-write the array in the vector  idiom

```
for( auto i = 0; &arr[i] != &arr[10]; i++ ){
}
```

Maps are more complicated, they have a different guard mechanism, but an iterator == `end()` never is valid.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/) , `.end()`  `Returns an iterator pointing to the past-the-end element in the sequence:`

It does not point to an element in the container ( the map in your case ), rather points outside of it.